# Why use clang and gcc, your include is different when you want use `int32_t` or `memcpy`?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, llvm

Why there are different includes between gcc48 and clang when you want use `int32_t` or `memcpy`?

when use gcc, after you include `<iostream>`, you also should include `<stdint.h>` and `<string.h>` for using `int32t` and `memcopy`

when use clang, you just need include `<iostream>`, and you can free use `int32t` and `memcopy`, stdint.h and string.h automatically included.

Why is that?
And can I run clang as gcc behavior ?

I use Mac OS.

Comment: You don't *need* `<iostream>` with either compiler to use `int32_t` or `memcpy`. You *should* include `<stdint.h>` and `<string.h>` with both compilers. The difference in behavior is because standard headers are allowed to include other headers, including other standard headers. clang must include the other 2 headers, while gcc doesn't, but you cannot depend on the current behavior of either compiler.

Comment: It is ridiculous that when we use gcc and include <iostream>, we need include <string.h> to use memcpy, but clang don't need.

Comment: It's ridiculous that you're harping about something this minor. Your code will **not** be portable unless you include both `stdint.h` and `string.h` if you're going to use `int32_t` and `memcpy`. Worry about that instead of worrying about how to make one compiler behave like another. And if you really don't care about writing correct code, what you should do is look up the names of all standard headers listed in the standard, create your own header, say `icanhazallstdheaderz`, include the names of the headers you found in it. Now include that one file, and all compilers will behave the same.

Comment: You might as well ask 'why do I need <iostream>' after including <cstdint> or <cstring> - it makes about as much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Probably that's because clang's standard library happens to include `<stdint.h>` and `<string.h>` already in `<iostream>` for its own private reasons; this is not guaranteed, and, as you can see, your `gcc`'s standard library doesn't work that way.

Don't rely on such behavior; always include the needed files regardless of these coincidences.

Comment: How to make clang's behavior as gcc? I tried to make their libstdc++ same, they use same <iostream> file, but the differences also exist.

Comment: @frogcjn: So, you're saying you'd prefer to modify your environment to compile your incorrect code, rather than write correct code?

Comment: My school use gcc, but I want to use clang with Xcode 5.0 to edit my code. Xcode must use clang, you cannot change its compiler to gcc. So I want to change the behavior of clang, let clang more like gcc.

Comment: @frogcjn: if you have the g++ standard library installed, you could try using the command-line switch `-stdlib=libstdc++`, but different versions of the library may work in different ways in these respects. The only way to be standard-compliant is to make sure you include all the needed headers (as specified by the documentation) for the functions/classes/... you use in your code, without relying on "accidental inclusion".

Comment: @MatteoItalia I have tried. But the difference also exits.

Comment: @frogcjn: as already said, this may differ even between different versions of the same library (probably the versions of libstdc++ present on your machine and at your school is different); again, the only way to write portable code is to check the documentation and always include the needed headers.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks. I already find a method to change the compiler of Xcode from clang to gcc.